# how can i get data insights from pages facebook without have role admin or analyst in this page with graph api?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

I need to get data insights from pages facebook without have role admin or analyst in this page with graph api, just with application registration.

Answer (score 1):

Before your app can make calls to read, update, or post to Pages you need to get a page access token. With this token you can view Page settings, make updates to page information and manage a Page.

Graph API Doc : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/access-tokens

Comment: I now that but my problem is it possible to get data insights from pages facebook without have role admin, because it's not pracise to apply every time the page administrator to give you the admin role.

Comment: @khalid: _“is it possible to get data insights from pages facebook without have role admin”_ - no, of course not. _“because it's not pracise to apply every time the page administrator to give you the admin role”_ - that isn’t necessary, they just need to grant your app access. Page admin logs into your app and grants necessary permissions.

Comment: How can I grant my app to access a page facebook.

Comment: @CBroe, How can i do that?

Comment: By having a page admin login to your app, and grant it `manage_pages` permission ...

Comment: @CBroe, is it necessary to have a role admin in this page facebook?

Comment: Yes, without admin access to the page, those insights are none of your business.

Comment: @CBroe, is the installation of the application on the page is not enough, because it is difficult if I want to extract the insights of 200 pages facebook must ask the administrator of each page to give me the role admin on each page.

Comment: _“must ask the administrator of each page to give me the role admin on each page”_ - or you let an existing page admin grant your app the necessary permissions. And no, “installation” of the app on the page is not enough.

Comment: @CBroe, "you let an existing page admin grant your app the necessary permissions",how can i do?,I would like to test this.

Comment: As I said before, you let them login to your app and grant it the required permissions. If you have not worked with Facebook login before, then start with the documentation on that.

Comment: @CBroe, I succeeded to extract insights from a facebook page, here are the steps I followed:
-I registered on the app.
-I generated a user access token with permissions manage_page, read_insights.
-I generated an access token page for this page.

Comment: @CBroe, but I'am not understand,  "you let them login to your app and grant it the required permissions".

Comment: @CBroe, what do you mean by that app, I think an application  create from Facebook Developers.

Comment: Yes, of course. An app is the basis for doing anything with the API. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/register

Comment: @CBroe, when you create a facebook app, no one can connect to your app because when you want to create an app you need a facebook account, how can I let someone connect to my app.

Comment: What? That doesn't even make sense. _"how can I let someone connect to my app"_ - by sending them to the login dialog.

Comment: @CBroe, If you have a tutorial about this,please.

Comment: @CBroe, how i can add FB login in page facebook? I choose website or what.

Comment: I read this article,i didn't find type page facebook, just facebook games,android,ios,website.

Comment: @CBroe, I don't understand why I need a website or android application, for adding facebook login, I don't have a website.

Comment: @CBroe,yes I understand what you mean,I did that but the problem I can not get to the application right manage_pagesand read_insights,because facebook request to film a video that shows your use. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review/how-to-submit#newsubmission

Comment: If your app is going to be used by the general public, then you need to get it reviewed. If not - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#faq_180362122361921

Comment: @CBroe, even if my app is in development and therefore unavailable to the public, when I check manage_page and read_insights, it asks me Complete the details: for this item before sending it for review.

Comment: Are you referring to the message shown in the login dialog? That only tells you that you need to get your app reviewed before you can ask normal users for those permissions - it does not stop a user with a role in the app from proceeding with the dialog ...

Comment: @CBroe, This is the code of my button,<div class="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="1" data-size="large" data-scope="manage_pages,read_insights" data-button-type="continue_with" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="false" data-use-continue-as="false"></div>.

Comment: Yeah, and, so what …?

Comment: when I check manage_page and read_insights in my application, it asks me Complete the details: for this item before sending it for review.

Comment: @CBroe,When I try to login with facebook login with a compte developper for my application, I have this message:""Envoyer pour examen de connexion
Certaines autorisations ci-dessous n’ont pas été approuvées pour une utilisation par Facebook.Soumettre maintenant à examen ou en savoir plus.""

Comment: Again: This is just a message reminding you that you need to submit for review, before the general public can use your app. Any user with a role in the app can proceed despite that message.

Comment: @CBroe, if this user is admin in some page,when he conneted with my buton facebook login ,I can get data insights of their pages?

Comment: If they grant you the necessary permissions, yes ... But for that to work before review, you need to add them to a role in your app (admin/ developer/ tester), and for that to work they need to have their account registered as a developer.

Comment: @CBroe, thank you ,I will create a facebook page by another account and I will try this scenario, after I will answer you.

Comment: @CBroe, how i can get access token.

Comment: Either implement Facebook login, or create one in Graph API Explorer (the latter for your own account only, of course.)

Comment: @CBroe, I get it from response with method FB.getAuthResponse, when some one click in facebook login.after I will generate a page access token.

Comment: @CBroe, I need to know if I have a right to make my application public with permission read_insights and manage_pages?